# Will "new" cause memory leak in function as well?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Assume we want to declare a function in C++, in which I declare a local variable `int p=new int [10];` and I do some operations afterwards and in the end I `return p;` .

As is often said, if we use `new` , we must `delete`. But I think in this case, we should NOT delete, right? Otherwise, it can't return p at all, right? However, I am also thinking if we should delete the item the function returns when we test it in `int main()`.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `vector<int>`?

Comment: The point for me to ask the question is to figure out how exactly the memory allocation works

Comment: @CanCan, while I understand your question about allocation, I wish to stress that NicolBolas is right and that usually, returning vector<int> is the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is that for every `new` there must be a `delete` (and for every `new[]` a `delete[]` <sup>*</sup>), but it need not be in the same scope. It is common to have functions dynamically create an object and transfer ownership of that object to the caller. The caller will then be responsible for deleting the memory.

That being said, you should avoid directly calling `new` and `delete` in your code, and prefer using other constructs that are *safe* (take care of the memory automatically for you). In the particular case you mention, a `std::vector<int>` initialized with 10 elements will have little overhead over the pointer and will ensure that the memory is released whenever the object is destroyed.

<sup>*</sup> Depending on your implementation, there might be cases where you `new` (or `new[]`) and not delete, if the memory is handed to a smart pointer. For example in C++11 you could do:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> f() {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[10]); // new is unmatched
    // ...
    return p;
}
```

This is fine, as handling the pointer to the `std::unique_ptr` ensures that it will call `delete[]` internally when it goes out of scope (if not moved to a different smart pointer).

Comment: The reason why I am always afraid of using vector or list or some other STL is that I don't know if they support automatic conversion. For example, I declare a function like inputsomething(vector<int> a), and delcare a as int a[10], will they do auto conversiont? Or in other words, can I declare any other similar STL if I declare one in the function?

Comment: @Cancan: No, it will not convert from an array to a `vector`, although it is quite simple to do the conversion manually with the constructors provided in `std::vector`. On the other direction, from `std::vector` to a pointer you can just pass `&v[0]` (i.e. the address of the first element), since the vector guarantees contiguity of the elements. Another question is whether you want to use raw arrays in general. If `std::vector` becomes the *vocabulary* type to deal with sequences of elements, then all your functions would use it and there would not be any need of conversions.

Comment: Oh, that's also cool, and could you please tell me which constructor it is to convert a normal array to a vector?

Comment: @Cancan: The constructor that takes two iterators, but note that this will require a dynamic allocation. It is better to use `std::vector` in the first place (and remember to pass by `const&` rather than value if you need not modify or copy the vector in the function). `int array[10]; std::vector<int> v(array, array+10);` (You should not hardcode the size of the array, but rather use some code that will infer it for you, but that is out of the scope of this comment)

Answer (score 3):

The caller would need to know you returned something created with `new []`, and call `delete []` when necessary. There is a lot of scope for error in such a construct. Better return something that takes care of its own memory, such as an `std::vector` or an `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

delete should be done when the program is done using the array. It doesn't have to be in the same function.

If `delete` always needed to be done when the function ends, it would get added automatically (`unique_ptr` is a way to tell C++11 to automatically free something `new` when the function ends)

Answer (score 0):

They are allocated from heap. So you can and should delete on anywhere outside the function.

New and Delete does not use stack. Same for malloc and free.

Answer (score 0):

You can `delete []` `p` in the new scope it is returned after you are done with it. However, it is not a good practice to just  allocate a memory with `new` and giving the ownership to another scope. You can utilize `std::vector` or [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).